# Solution to a tricky inequality (math analysis)

Tags: analysis

Let $p>1$ and put $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$, so $1/p+1/q=1$. Show that for any $x>0$ and $y>0$, we have 
$$ xy \le \frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{y^q}{q}$$
And find where the equality holds.

So far, I have simply tried to multiply through the RHS of the above expression and see what would happen, plugged in for $q$ and I got this:

$$ pxy \le  x^p+(p-1)y^\frac{p}{p-1} $$
We also know that $q>1$ by its definition and using $p>1$, but I am not quite sure how to proceed. Any suggestions? 
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Since $x > 0$, write $$x = e^{t/p}$$ for some $t$. Likewise $y = e^{s/q}$. Then

$$xy = e^{t/p + s/q} \le \frac{e^t}{p} + \frac{e^s}{q}$$

since the exponential is convex.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about using the properties of convexity. So then the case $p=1$ and $q=1$ would satisfy the equality if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Darkel90 You've assumed that $p > 1$, though. Note that $e^z$ is *strictly* convex, though, so...

Comment: So would there not be a solution for $p$ and $q% such that the equality holds?

Comment: @Darkel90 Equality holds if and only if $x^p = y^q$ iff $e^t = e^s$ iff $s = t$.

Comment: Thank you. It's been a long day and I really should have seen this last part. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Darkel90 You're very welcome :)